Remove last character of first word
I want to remove the last character from the first word in a stream of strings using sed, e.g., 20240801T00:48 should become 20240801T00:4. I've tried
sed 's/\(.\)\([^ ]*\) /\2

but it doesn't change anything. If I reference group 1 that replaces the whole word with the last character (as you would expect). Not sure what I'm doing wrong, or if there's a better way...

There are 29000 question using sed tag on Stackoverflow so it is quite strange when someone decided to close vote with the reason that a sed and regex question is not about programming.. SO is already facing considerably lower volume of questions and here we are discouraging posters to ask genuine questions.

Based on the input shown, you don't really need any capture groups here.
Just use:
echo "20240801T00:48 foo bar" | sed 's/. / /'

20240801T00:4 foo bar

Here:

.  will match any character followed by a space, which will match first space instance only
In the replacement we place the space back in the output


Correct! We need to use a capturing group when we want to return only that part of the pattern.

If Perl is an option, you can use this Perl one-liner:
echo "20240801T00:48 foo bar" | perl -pe 's{^(\S+)\S}{$1}'
20240801T00:4 foo bar

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
-e : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
-p : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to $_ by default. Add print $_ after each loop iteration.
s{PATTERN}{REPLACEMENT} : Replace regex PATTERN with REPLACEMENT.
^ : Matches the beginning of the line.
(\S+)\S : Matches the maximum number of non-whitespace characters, captured using parentheses into capture group 1 (later referenced with $1), followed by one (last) non-whitespace character (which is not captured, so does not get included into $1).
See also:

perldoc perlrun: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches
perldoc perlrequick: Perl regular expressions quick start


This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E 's/(\S+)\S/\1/' file

If a word must contain at least 2 non-white space characters, the above solution will remove the last character.
If however a word may contain at least 1 non-white space characters, then use:
sed -E 's/(\S*)\S/\1/' file

